# Uploading a xml file into the AEM DAM

Tags: java, adobe, aem, sling

I want to upload a xml file into the AEM DAM. The xml file is sitemap.xml which I read using InputStream. But how do I write ResourceResolver ?     `ResourceResolver resourceResolver = resolverFactory.getAdministrativeResourceResolver(null)`
 is deprecated now. I am following this tutorial but facing this resource resolver problem. What will be the correct syntax ?

Comment: misleading title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method resolverFactory.getAdministrativeResourceResolver() is deprecated for security reasons. This gave you an admin-session without any permission checking.

It is replaced by resolverFactory.getServiceResourceResolver(). This gives you a normal session with a pre-configured user. To configure it, go to the admin console (e.g. http://localhost:4502/system/console/configMgr ) and find the settings for *Apache Sling Service User Mapper Service*.

For your tuturial it is fair enough, just to use the admin user for your Bundle as service user.

Also look at the Adobe documentation for this issue: https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/6-3/sites/administering/using/security-service-users.html

Comment: Now, I used the resolverFactory.getServiceResourceResolver(). I have created a system user and give all the permission but still I am getting "Cannot derive user name for bundle com.xyz-aem.core [475] and sub service testService". I also mapped the user on 'Apache Sling Service User Mapper Service'. It is a login exception. What is the wrong thing I am doing ? Any idea ?

Comment: I just tried it myself, and you may run into the same issue. With 6.3 you can only map to service users. You have to follow https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/6-3/sites/administering/using/security-service-users.html#Creatinganewserviceuser to create one. Normally you use a tool for creating them automatically (e.g. https://github.com/Netcentric/accesscontroltool)

Comment: Your config should be then: com.xyz-aem.core:testService=myserviceuser

Comment: You will get the error message " "Cannot derive user name for bundle com.xyz-aem.core [475] and sub service testService"" too, if you just map it to a normal user (which could login). Thats why I guess, you took a normal user.

Comment: Thank you so much @Alexander for your suggestions. It worked finally.

Answer (score 2):

You can now use `resourceFactory.getServiceResourceResolver(paramMap)` method of `org.apache.sling.api.resource.ResourceResolverFactory`.

```
ResourceResolver resourceResolver = null;
    try {
        Map<String, Object> paramMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        paramMap.put(ResourceResolverFactory.SUBSERVICE, "writeService");
        resourceResolver = resourceFactory.getServiceResourceResolver(paramMap);
    } catch (LoginException e) {
        log.error("Login Exception : " + e);
    }
```

Also, Configure your subservice in [Felix config manager](http://localhost:4502/system/console/configMgr) in `Apache Sling Service User Mapper Service` as

`<bundle Symbolic Name>:<sub-service name>=<system-user-name>`

[image]

you also need to create System user using [CRX Explorer](http://localhost:4502/crx/explorer/index.jsp) and click on **User Administration** and give permission of the relative paths.

Comment: I already did the same this. It is resolved. Thank you for your suggestion.